# Can database backup and restore using pgdump resolve transaction wraparound in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I know the solution advocated is `VACUUM`. However, I was interested in knowing whether old versions of `XID`s are marked as frozen when restoring a database dump  using `pg_dump`.

Also, this [blogpost](https://blog.sentry.io/2015/07/23/transaction-id-wraparound-in-postgres.html) mentions that the transaction wraparound issue was resolved after truncating one of the large tables that had not been auto-vacuumed. How did the truncation help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When restoring database from pg_dump, it will re initialize transaction id on the database. So, just like the beginning You create a database. It needs time for another transaction wraparound.

Transaction id wraparound is count on a per table level. If a table is truncated, but still another table is possible to be wraparound.

Hope it helps